# Undefined array members are not zero! (c)

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

My code is:

```
int main()
{
    int i,*A,N,menu=0,x;

    printf("\n\n\n   What is the size:   "   );
    scanf("%d",&N);

    A=(int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));


    printf("\n   enter Array's ");

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("\n    %d. element...:   ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    }

   for(i=4;i<14;i++){
        printf("\n    %d. element:   ",A[i]);

    }
}
```

For example i say 4 for N and enter elements, then when i print out from 4 to 10 for example, there are a lot of random numbers. I am trying to make a binary tree and the condition is not equal to zero. I thought other elements would be zero sothe while loop could understand the array was out of limit.

AM i doing wrong or should i use another condition?

```
void add(int x,int * A){
int i=0;

while(A[i]!=NULL){

    if(x<A[i]){
        i=i*2+1;

    }
    else{
        i=i*2+2;

    }
 }
 A[i]=x;
}
```

Comment: If you have 4 elements it's Undefined Behaviour to access `A[4]`, `A[5]`, ..., `A[13]`. The only valid elements are `A[0]`, `A[1]`, `A[2]`, and `A[3]`.

Comment: What did you expect? You didn't allocate it, nor fill it in. The machine is allowed to do whatever it wants with memory that isn't yours.

Comment: Among other things, you should always check the value returned by `malloc`; it returns a null pointer if the allocation fails. And `A=(int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));` is better written as `A = malloc(N * sizeof *A);`

Comment: sorry i added my binary add code. So condition will be never true?

Comment: `while(A[i]!=NULL)` that's an invalid terminating condition

Comment: while(A[i]!=NULL) or while(A[i]!=0) i tried both

Comment: So how will i understand if that slot is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong.

There is no guarantee about what will be in the memory that you don't own. The memory that you are accessing after `index >= N` could have been previously been used elsewhere. The `free()`'d memory is not zero`ed out, it still contains the content that was there when it was being used - **Garbage** !.

Comment: Well, that's not true for your program memory. You don't know what it contains unless you explicitly set it to `zero`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are accessing array out of bounds. With `N = 4` you can access only upto `a[3]` (as array indexing starts from `0` in C).
Accessing unallocated memory location would not necessarily give you `0`. It can contain any garbage value.